# Encountering Challenges in Mitigating OpenSSL Vulnerability on Ubuntu-22

Tags: openssl, trivy

Encountering Challenges in Mitigating openssl Vulnerability on Ubuntu Despite Upgrade Efforts.
I had run the command `docker run aquasec/trivy rootfs /`  to get vulnerabilities in Ubuntu-22,
Output is as follows:

| Library | Vulnerability | Severity | Status | Installed Version | Fixed Version | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| libcrypto3 | CVE-2023-5363 | HIGH | fixed | 3.1.3-r0 | 3.1.4-r0 | openssl:Incorrect cipherkey |
|  | CVE-2023-5678 |  |  |  | 3.1.4-r1 | and IV length processing |

openssl current version is 3.0.2.`sudo apt update and upgrade` commands didnot help to upgrade.

I have followed below steps to upgrade openssl to 3.1.4 version
Link (for steps i followed) : "https://www.golinuxcloud.com/install-openssl-ubuntu/"

1. Download and install

```
sudo wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.1.4.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzvf openssl-3.1.4.tar.gz -C /usr/local/src/ && sudo mv /usr/local/src/openssl-  
   3\.1.4/\* /usr/local/src
```

2. Switch to /usr/local/src directory

```
  cd /usr/local/src/
   sudo ./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlibsudo make &&
   sudo make test
   sudo make install
```

3. add a file to ld.so.conf.d directory

```
   cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
   sudo nano openssl-3.1.4.conf
   Enter content:  /usr/local/ssl/lib64
```

4. Create necessary links and cache for newly added libraries and add path

```
   sudo ldconfig -v
   sudo mv /usr/bin/c_rehash /usr/bin/c_rehash.backup
   sudo mv /usr/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl.backup
   export PATH="/usr/local/ssl/bin:$PATH"
   source \~/.bashrc
```

5. View the openssl version

```
   $openssl version
   OpenSSL 3.1.4 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.4 15 Mar 2022)
```

6. View dpkg -l output

```
   $dpkg -l|grep openssl
   ii  openssl       3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12         amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit
```

In above ,openssl version command output updated correctly to 3.1.4 new version.
But dpkg is still reporting old version(3.0.2)
WHY openssl version is not updating in dpkg output???
And i have run vulnerability command again,output is same as before:

| Library | Vulnerability | Severity | Status | Installed Version | Fixed Version | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| libcrypto3 | CVE-2023-5363 | HIGH | fixed | 3.1.3-r0 | 3.1.4-r0 | openssl:Incorrect cipherkey |
|  | CVE-2023-5678 |  |  |  | 3.1.4-r1 | and IV length processing |

Can anyone help me to fix above issue????